# Docker install of AZCore results in authserver+worldserver doesn't exist error

Tags: docker, azerothcore

I'm trying to spin up a fresh server using the azerothcore docker installation guide. I have completed all of the early installation steps, up until running the containers. Upon running the containers (for worldserver and authserver) i see the following output from the containers. It appears the destination of the world and auth servers in dist/bin is missing, how may i resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your docker settings. Make sure you have enough memory. If containers have low memory they will not finish the compile. Check if you have build issues.